# how to keep multiline string in JSON and parse it in angular2

Tags: json, angular

I have a json file having multiline strings in a key.

```
"hello \r\n how are \r\n you"
```

I am trying to parse it using angular2 sanitizer

```
<p>Explanation : <span [innerHTML] = "explanationJSONString)"></span></p>
```

in the output, `\r\n` is omitted in HTML.

How can I have multiple line josn data in angualr2 template?

I also try just `\` but it also doesnt work.

Comment: Have you tried just using `\n`

Comment: You should use <br> tag for newline if you are going to use it in html.

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse [pipes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html) fot this.

Your markup

```
<span [innerHTML] = "explanationJSONString() | break"></span>
```

Your pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'break'
})
export class BreakPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): any {
    return value.replace(/\r\n/g, '<br>');
  }
}
```